# I want to get a sum of the list except for the iterative value

Tags: python, list

columnData.tolist() outputs the following

```
[19.51 15.45 16.67  0.   12.06  5.97 15.56  0.   12.8  17.58]
```

I want it so, that each position in the list will be converted a sum of all other values.

Below is the code I am trying.

```
templ = [ sum( columnData.tolist().pop(i) )
          for i,l in enumerate(columnData.tolist()) ]
```

And the output is:
'''
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
'''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple implementation using list comprehension.

```
lst = [] #your_list
s = sum(lst)
new_lst = [s-i for i in lst]
```

Comment: Nice answer, and clean solution.

Comment: @S3DEV that's the best part about Python

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I did think I was doing something unnecessary and the solution would be simple.